# Need help moving character diagonally

Tags: java

Making a game for class and I am having trouble getting my character to move diagonally. I think I'm doing something wrong in detecting multiple key presses because I tested walkDownLeft with a single key but when I try to get it to trigger with the left and right key it just goes left. Am I missing something or is the way I'm using not just going to do what I want?

```
public boolean AkeyDown(Event e, int key) {
      if (key == 1004) {
        Player.walkUp = true;
    }
    if (key == 1005 && key != 1006) {
        Player.walkDown = true;
    }
    if (key == 1005 && key == 1006) {
        Player.walkDownLeft = true;
    }
    if (key == 1006 && key != 1005) {
        Player.walkLeft = true;
    }
    if (key == 1007) {
        Player.walkRight = true;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean AkeyUp(Event e, int key) {   
    if (key == 1004) {
        Player.walkUp = false;
    }
    if (key == 1005 && key != 1006) {
        Player.walkDown = false;
    }
    if (key == 1005 && key == 1006) {
        Player.walkDownLeft = false;
    }
    if (key == 1006 && key != 1005) {
        Player.walkLeft = false;
    }
    if (key == 1007) {
        Player.walkRight = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `key` can't be `1005` AND `1006` at the same time.  Better to use a series of flags for up/down, left/right, then simply update the x/y position based on those flags

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on MadProgrammer's comment.  There are three types of key events in Java, `keyPressed`, `keyReleased`, and keyTyped.

`keyPressed` and `keyReleased` will never detect more than one character.  Even if you hit Ctrl and then also pressed c (as if to copy) you would get two `keyPressed` events, one for Ctrl and one for c.

`keyTyped` will combine some combinations of multiple key presses into one and would generate a single `keyTyped` event (C with modifier Ctrl pressed) for the Ctrl+c sequence.  However, keyTyped is only going to combine modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Super, etc.)  It will not combine two arrow keys.  That means if the user pressed the up arrow and then shortly pressed the right arrow you would get two `keyPressed` events, one for each arrow.  If they then released the keys you would get two `keyReleased` events and two `keyTyped` events.

So this is why you are never getting into the walkDownLeft scenario.  There will be no event with both keys triggered.  I would recommend only have walkLeft, walkRight, walkUp, and walkDown.  Then in your other thread which reads those states have something like:

```
if(player.walkUp && !player.walkRight && !player.walkLeft) {
    //Move up
} else if (player.walkUp && player.walkRight) {
    //Move upRight
} else if (player.walkUp && player.walkLeft) {
    //Move upLeft
} //...
```

Those if statements could be optimized but I'm leaving them as is for readability.